# How to get rid of two subscribe in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular

How to turn two subscribe into one? Do I need to use any rxjs operator?

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.aService.aa.subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;

     this.bService.bb.subscribe(data => {
      this.data2 = data.map(AA.AAFromDefinition);
       });
     });
}
```

Comment: Are they the same service?

Comment: I don't understand the question, from the code it doesn't follow?

Answer (score 0):

use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). Note this method executes two api calls in parallel, assuming that is what you want.

Also don't forget to add it to a subscription, so that it can be unsubscribed during component destroy.

```
    subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription.add(
            forkJoin([this.aService.aa, this.bService.bb]).subscribe((data1, data2) => {
                this.data = data1;
                this.data2 = data2.map(AA.AAFromDefinition);
            })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: Parameter 'data1' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage - this error what does it mean?

Comment: @rdsm2 just set a type for each of the parameters, meaning: the api call will return a format, that needs to be added as a type (typescript interface), if you don't want to set a type you can do `(data1: any, data2: any)` like so

Comment: Now I have an error: No reload matches this connection.
  Overload 1 of 5...

Comment: @rdsm2 can you provide the full error? if possible a stackblitz with the error alone replicated?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that in component create observable

```
  data$: Observable<{ data: any, data2: any }>;

  constructor(aService: serviceA, bService: serviceB) {
    this.data$ = combineLatest([aService.aa, bService.bb])
      .pipe(map(([aa, bb]) => {
          return { data: aa, data2: bb.map(AA.AAFromDefinition) };
        },
      ));
  }
```

Then in template

```
{{(data$ | async).data}}
```